# find files with similar ID from different folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I have two folder A and B. in each folder I have text files containing participant IDs starting from 100. some files can be present in both folders. i want to check if both the file names match each other by id and get them.

file name example: result_100.txt

I have written a logic, but it is taking too long to find.

```
def find_id:
    returns id

for i in folder_A:
    for j in forder_b:
        if find_id(i) == find_id(j):
            print(i, "--", j)
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: hi @SharimIqbal, thanks for the suggestion,  my above logic is taking more time to iterate over the items. is there any way i can make it faster ?

Comment: check my answer below.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer but i have only the participant id as common identifier in my file name. my filename also contains date and other things for which the list intersection might not work.

Comment: You can try once.

Comment: tried. but it returns a empty list

Answer (score 0):

Easy way.

```py
import os
first = os.listdir('Enter Your Path To Folder A')
second = os.listdir('Enter Your Path To Folder B')
same = list(set(first).intersection(set(second)))

print(same)
```